# Joda time bug on certain Android devices?

Tags: android, jodatime

I'm using joda-time 1.6.2 in an Android app and I am getting some crash reports

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid format: "8:00 AM" is malformed at "AM"
```

And the code that triggers is is the following:

```
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("hh:mm a");
LocalTime lt = formatter.parseDateTime(value).toLocalTime();
```

I can't reproduce this crash on my phones so it happens only on certain Android devices and I have no clue why.

Comment: What is value? Where is it set?

Comment: value is "8:00 AM". It appears also in the exception: "Invalid format: "8:00 AM" "

Comment: Ye but what is the type and where do you load the value and instantiate it to 8:00 AM?

Comment: My guess is that joda might not be compatible with all android locals...

Comment: It's a String value = "8:00 AM". In a previous version I tried using lower-case "8:00 am" and now I am thinking of using in the next version "08:00 AM".

Comment: I have same problem. I am using 2.3 version and when I tested it with JR6 or JR7 works fine, but in android says:  "Invalid format: "8:00 AM"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was faced with the same issue after the release of Android 5. Only devices running this version would crash.

> This is probably a localization issue. It appears that your default local does not know the "AM"-string, but something else.

[See my post for details and my solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28286732/jodatime-issues-on-android-5-0/28292342?noredirect=1#comment45195301_28292342)